# SharePoint 2010 RESTful API listdata.svc can't find list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest, listdata.svc

I'm trying to use listdata.svc on a SP2010 list and I get "The website cannot display the page". It works on other lists in that same site and even on a duplicate of the list on another site, where I exported the list and recreated it. What could be some reasons it won't work on this particular list?

Comment: Can you post the URL you are using

Comment: <my url>/_vti_bin/listData.svc/list

Comment: You should use Fiddler to diagnose the exact response message returned by the server. Usually it contains further detalis (errors / error codes) in such cases, that are not displayed by the browser.

Comment: Are you using the internal name of the list or the title?

Comment: No, the display name.

Comment: Can you share the display name of the list and the full rest url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was a column somehow causing the error. After removing the column from the list, it worked. I don't know why the column would cause that. There is another column of that type (calculated) in the list that doesn't cause listdata.svc to fail.

Comment: this is totally patehtic. I am having the same issue in an o365 site AFTER TWO YEARS.

Comment: microsoft documentation is HORRIBLE

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue caused by a calculated column with HTML. The calculation created a hyperlink, so I was able to easily replace the column with a Hyperlink column. Thanks for posting.